# Connect form to jQuery post with a button

Tags: jquery, forms, post, live

I have this code and I use it to show some results live on my site. This form works after filling the field automatically. I want to do this thing with a button. Here is my code:

```js
function getStates() {
  var couplername = $('#couplername').val();

  $.post("http://memarooneh.com/wp-content/themes/publisher/includes/subscribe.php", {
    couplername: couplername
  }, function(data) {
    $("#order_price").show();
    $("#order_price").html(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `getStates()` now? Just call it under a click event on whatever button you need

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It will show in `<div id="order_price"></div>` without any click

Comment: Something *has* to trigger that function.

Comment: Could you share the HTML behind this JS snippet? And you should better describe the scenario you want to achieve, it seems like you're a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

brittle way of posting AJAX request via function you created is use `onClick` handler like below

```html
<button onclick="getStates()" id="subscribe_btn">Subscribe</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#target" ).click(getStates);
});

function getStates() {

  var couplername = $('#couplername').val();
  var couplercount = $('#couplercount').val();
  var couplerlathing = $('#couplerlathing').val();
  var couplerwhois = $('#couplerwhois').val();
  var couplerdetailsname = $('#couplerdetailsname').val();
  var couplerdetailsid = $('#couplerdetailsid').val();
  var couplerdetailsnumber = $('#couplerdetailsnumber').val();

  $.post(
     "http://memarooneh.com/wp-content/themes/publisher/includes/subscribe.php", 
     { couplername:couplername, couplercount:couplercount, couplerlathing:couplerlathing, couplerwhois:couplerwhois, couplerdetailsname:couplerdetailsname, couplerdetailsid:couplerdetailsid, couplerdetailsnumber:couplerdetailsnumber },
     function(data) {
       $("#order_price").show();
       $("#order_price").html(data);
     });
}
```